# My ViewModel only returns the id asp net core 2.0 tag helper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I can only get the dishId from my form asp.net Core with asp tag helpers. I have tried both asp-route and submit form but nothing helps. I don´t know what I´m doing wrong. Please tell me if I need to add something so you understand me. I don´t usually post here but I use the forum pretty much. Can someone help me?

```
 public IActionResult Edit(EditDishViewModel model)
   {
    return null;
   }
```

in this line in the controller, model only return EditDish and it´s id. Nothing else.

View

```
@model PizzAkuten.Models.EditDishViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<h4>Dish</h4>
<form asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="Order" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="EditDish.DishId" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="EditDish.Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="EditDish.Name" class="form-control" 
               value="@Model.EditDish.Name" disabled/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="EditDish.Price" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="EditDish.Price" class="form-control" 
      value="@Model.EditDish.Price" disabled/>
   </div>
         <label asp-for="EditDish.DishIngredients" class="control-
     label">Ingredienser</label>
      <div class="form-group">

    @foreach (var dish in Model.EditDish.DishIngredients)
    {
        <label asp-for="@dish.Ingredient.Name" class="control-
 label">@dish.Ingredient.Name</label>
        <input asp-for="@dish.Ingredient.IsChecked" class="form-control" 
 type="checkbox" value="true" />

    }
   </div>
<div class="form-group">

    @foreach (var ing in Model.ExtraIngredients)
    {
        <label asp-for="@ing.Ingredients.Name" class="control-
    label">@ing.Ingredients.Name</label>
        <input asp-for="@ing.IsChecked" class="form-control" type="checkbox" 
  value=""/>
    }
   </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</form>

   <div>
      <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
     </div>
```

Controller

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int dishId)
    {
        if (dishId == 0)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        var ingredients = _context.Ingredients.ToList();
        var dish = await _context.Dishes.Include(d => d.DishIngredients).ThenInclude(di => di.Ingredient)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.DishId == dishId);

        var model = new EditDishViewModel();

        var ingList = new List<ExtraIngredient>();

        foreach (var item in ingredients)
        {
            var ing = new ExtraIngredient();
            item.IsChecked = true;
            ing.Ingredients = item;
            ingList.Add(ing);
        }
        model.EditDish = dish;
        model.ExtraIngredients = ingList;

        if (dish == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Edit(EditDishViewModel model)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

Models

```
    public class ExtraIngredient
{
    public Ingredient Ingredients { get; set; }

    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}



    public int IngredientId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public List<DishIngredient> DishIngredients { get; set; }

      public class DishIngredient
{
    public int DishId { get; set; }
    public Dish Dish { get; set; }
    public int IngredientId { get; set; }
    public Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }
}

    public class EditDishViewModel
{
    public Dish EditDish { get; set; }

    public List<ExtraIngredient> ExtraIngredients { get; set; }
}

  public class Dish
{
    public int DishId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Price { get; set; }

    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Ingredients")]
    public List<DishIngredient> DishIngredients { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Orderrader")]
    public List<OrderDish> OrderDishes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you create a simple view model for your view. with less nested structure.

Comment: Instead of <input asp-for="EditDish.Price".... /> shouldn't it be "Model.EditDish.Price" .... />  ??

Comment: First you cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls for a collection - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943). In addition, view models should not contain data models - they contain the properties of your data models that you need in the view. And do not set the `value` attribute - the tag helpers already do that correctly. Finally, your controls for `EditDish.Name` is disabled and disabled controls do not submit a value